# Android How to Read PDF pages using ViewPager

Tags: android, pdf, android-viewpager

I want to to use a ViewPager to display select PDF pages, I can do that with images, But I have no idea how load a PDF and access it's pages.
Do you have any ideas how to Read PDF pages using ViewPager?

Comment: use this https://github.com/JoanZapata/android-pdfview

Comment: And what have you tried?

Comment: Hi Sunny Kumar Aditya,  I tried to build the project,but it gives me errors.Can you tell me how to remove those errors